# Possible values for __STDC_ISO_10646__

Tags: c, unicode, iso

What are the possible values of the `__STDC_ISO_10646__` macro? Wikipedia has [a list of the versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set#Correlation_to_Unicode) of ISO 10646 corresponding to different Unicode versions, but with only the year, not the month, and the macro includes a month value.

**Edit:** Since several people are completely failing to understand the actual question. I am asking for a **specific list of numbers** which this macro may take as its value, and the corresponding editions of ISO 10646 for each number.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/history/publicationdates.html has a list of unicode version release dates but i'm not sure if that correlates with iso-10646 "along with all amendments and technical corrigenda"

Comment: Typically the ISO adoption and publication of new stuff from Unicode is not immediate, so I don't think those dates help.

Comment: Here is a page that shows the relationship between ISO 10646 releases and Unicode releases: http://babelstone.blogspot.com/2007/06/unicode-and-isoiec-10646.html

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Are the months in the table there the months of the publication of ISO 10646 editions that would correspond to the `__STDC_ISO_10646__` macro values? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @R..: The dates in the table are the Unicode release dates. But the table also shows which Unicode release was included in which ISO 10646 release.  What is not known is whether `__STDC_ISO_10646__` specifies the ISO release date or the Unicode release date.  I'm more curious why you need to worry about the value of `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, since really its main purpose is to inform whether the size of `wchar_t` is large enough to hold Unicode codepoints or not, and whether `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined or not handles that. The value of `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is a secondary concern, IMHO.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well I'm not sure how that's helpful then, since the ISO C macro takes its values from the ISO 10646 publication dates...

Comment: Well, if you know the ISO release date, then you know which Unicode version(s) were included in that release, per the table.

Comment: Yes but the whole question is **what are those release dates** that make up the possible values for the macro (and what does each possible value mean)? The question is asking for a mapping between that table and the possible values of the macro, so that table alone isn't a solution.

Comment: As the macro starts __ does that mean it's implementation specific and the headers/compiler is free to substitute whatever it likes into that macro.

Comment: @R.. Have you looked through the header files supplied with the compiler to see how it is set?  bear in mind as it starts __, that /could/ be set by the compiler, rather than in a header somewhere.

Comment: @Neil: No, it's specified in ISO C that the macro must be undefined if `wchar_t` is not UCS, and defined to a particular `yyyymmL` value corresponding to the version of ISO 10646 to which it conforms if `wchar_t` is UCS.

Comment: @R.. Perhaps there isn't a definitive list.  All that is known is that on the date the header, that defines this macro, was created, this library was up to date with the standard at that point.  This may or may not actually line up with any particular standard release.  If the standard was released in January 2014, and I released a library in February, I'm able to specify 201402L as a valid value.  In April, I release the library again and (assuming no update to unicode) specify 201404L.

Comment: http://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/WG2/docs/projects

Comment: @Neil Just because __ implies implementation defined does not mean that there are not restrictions on what the compiler may set. An implementation that sets the incorrect value (a value not corresponding to a correct date of a UNICODE resolution) is in error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at reports from ISO/IEC JTC1/SC2 (Coded Character Sets)/WG2 (Universal Coded Character Set), which are available at http://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/WG2/docs/projects, and cross-checking with http://babelstone.blogspot.com.es/2007/06/unicode-and-isoiec-10646.html, a preliminar list of publication dates can be compiled. Some dates may be off, in particular those with only month and year (and no day) were target dates.

- **1993-05-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993
- **1996-03-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 TC1
- **1996-10-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.1 (UTF-16)
- **1996-10-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.2 (UTF-8)
- **1996-10-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.3 (Code positions for control characters: C0, C1)
- **1996-10-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.4 (Removal of UTF-1)
- **1997-11-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.6 (Tibetan)
- **1997-11-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.7 (33 additional characters)
- **1997-12-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.8 (New annex on CJK ideographs)
- **1997-12-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.9 (Identifiers for characters)
- **1998-05-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.5 (Hangul syllables)
- **1998-07-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 TC2
- **1998-07-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.11 (Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics)
- **1998-09**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 TC3
- **1998-09-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.12 (Cherokee)
- **1998-10-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.10 (Ethiopic)
- **1998-10-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.13 (CJK unified ideographs)
- **1998-11-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.16 (Braille patterns)
- **1998-11-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.19 (Runic)
- **1998-11-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.20 (Ogham)
- **1999-05-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.23 (Bopomofo Extended and other characters)
- **1999-06-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.21 (Sinhala)
- **1999-07-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.17 (CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A)
- **1999-07-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.18 (Symbols and other characters)
- **1999-10**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.14 (Yi syllables and Yi radicals)
- **1999-10**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.22 (Keyboard symbols)
- **1999-10**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.25 (Khmer)
- **1999-10**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.26 (Burmese [Myanmar])
- **1999-10**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.27 (Syriac)
- **1999-11**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.24 (Thaana)
- **2000-02**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.15 (Radicals [Kang Xi and CJK supplement] and numerals)
- **2000-02**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.28 (Ideographic description characters)
- **2000-02 (published in 1999?)**             ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.29 (Mongolian)
- **2000-02 (published in 1999?)**          ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.30 (Additional Latin and other characters)
- **2000-03 (published in 1999?)**            ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 Amd.31 (Tibetan extension)
- **2000-09-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000, 2nd Edition (Part 1: Architecture and Basic Multilingual Plane)
- **2001-11-01**       ISO/IEC 10646-2:2001 (Part 2: Supplementary planes)
- **2002-07-15**       ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000 Amd.1 (Mathematical symbols and other characters)
- **2003-02 (not published separately?)**     ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000 Amd.2 (Limbu, Tai Le, Yijing and other characters)
- **2003-02 (not published separately?)**     ISO/IEC 10646-2:2001 Amd.1 (Aegean, Ugaritic and other characters)
- **2003-12-15**       ISO/IEC 10646:2003, 3rd Edition
- **2005-11-15**       ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.1 (Glagolitic, Coptic, Georgian and other characters)
- **2006-07-15**       ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.2 (N'Ko, Phags-pa, Phoenician and other characters)
- **2008-02-15**       ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.3 (Lepcha, Ol Chiki, Saurashtra, Vai and other characters)
- **2008-07-01**       ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.4 (Lanna, Cham, Game Tiles and other characters)
- **2008-12-01**       ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.5 (Tai Tham, Tai Viet, Avestan, Egyptian Hieroglyphs, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C and other characters)
- **2009-10????**      ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.6 (Bamum, Javanese, Lisu, Meetei Mayek, Samaritan and other characters)
- **2009-11???? (published in 2010?)** ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.7 (Mandaic, Batak, Brahmi and other characters)
- **(not published separately, incorporated into 2nd Edition)**        ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Amd.8 (Additional symbols, Bamum supplement, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D and other characters)
- **2011-03-15**       ISO/IEC 10646:2011, 2nd Edition (broken CJK-B charts due to font problems)
- **2012-06-01**       ISO/IEC 10646:2012, 3rd Edition
- **2013-04-15**       ISO/IEC 10646:2012 Amd.1 (Linear A, Palmyrene, Old North Arabian, Sindhi, Mro, Bassa Vah, and other characters)
- **(pending publication as part of 4th Edition)**                     ISO/IEC 10646:2012 Amd.2 (Caucasian Albanian, Psalter Pahlavi, Old Hungarian, Mahajani, Grantha, Modi, Pahawh, Hmong, Mende, and other characters)
- **(not yet published)**                      ISO/IEC 10646:2014, 4th Edition
- **2014?**                                    ISO/IEC 10646:2014 Amd.1 (Cherokee supplement and other characters)
- **2015?**                                    ISO/IEC 10646:2014 Amd.2 (Marchen, Nushu, Tangut ideographs, Zanabazar Square and other characters)

According to the previous list, the example in the ISO C standard (199712L), would correspond to ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 + Amendments 1-4,6-9, while glibc's 200009L would correspond to ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000. The example in the ISO C standard is just before Amendment 5, which moved and reorganized the Hangul block, an incompatible change sometimes referred to as the "Korean mess", which is explicitely alluded to in [the UTF-8 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-5) and elsewhere.

For completeness sake, here is a correspondence between Unicode and ISO 10646, compiled from data on http://www.unicode.org/history/publicationdates.html:

- **1991-10**          Unicode 1.0.0
- **1992-06**          Unicode 1.0.1
- **1993-06**          Unicode 1.1     ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993
- **1996-07**          Unicode 2.0     ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 + Amendments 5-7
- **1998-05**          Unicode 2.1     ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993 + Amendments 5-7 + 2 characters from Amendment 18 (Euro sign + Object Replacement Character (U+FFFC))
- **1999-09**          Unicode 3.0     ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000
- **2001-03**          Unicode 3.1     ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000 + ISO/IEC 10646-2:2001
- **2002-03**          Unicode 3.2     ISO/IEC 10646-1:2000 + Amendment 1 + ISO/IEC 10646-2:2001
- **2003-04**          Unicode 4.0     ISO/IEC 10646:2003
- **2005-03**          Unicode 4.1     ISO/IEC 10646:2003 + Amendment 1
- **2006-07**          Unicode 5.0     ISO/IEC 10646:2003 + Amendments 1-2 + 4 characters from Amendment 3 (Devanagari letters GGA, JJA, DDDA, BBA)
- **2008-04**          Unicode 5.1     ISO/IEC 10646:2003 + Amendments 1-4
- **2009-10**          Unicode 5.2     ISO/IEC 10646:2003 + Amendments 1-6
- **2010-10**          Unicode 6.0     ISO/IEC 10646:2011 + Indian Rupee sign
- **2012-01**          Unicode 6.1     ISO/IEC 10646:2012
- **2012-09**          Unicode 6.2     ISO/IEC 10646:2012 + Turkish Lira sign (included in Amd.1)
- **2013-09**          Unicode 6.3     ISO/IEC 10646:2012 + Turkish Lira sign + Bidirectional Isolates (LRI, RLI, FSI, PDI) + Arabic Letter MARK (ALM) (included in Amd.2)
- **2014-06**          Unicode 7.0     ISO/IEC 10646:2012 + Amendments 1-2 + Ruble sign (to be included in ISO/IEC 10646:2014)

Unicode has had several incompatible changes to character properties (not covered in ISO/IEC 10646). Some of them are mentioned in the [proposal for a Cherokee supplement](http://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC2/WG2/docs/n4487.pdf), and in [RFC6452 (The Unicode Code Points and Internationalized Domain Names for Applications (IDNA) - Unicode 6.0)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6452/):

- Unicode 3.0.0: U+01AA (LATIN LETTER REVERSED ESH LOOP), U+01BE (LATIN LETTER INVERTED GLOTTAL STOP WITH STROKE), U+01BF (LATIN LETTER WYNN), U+03F3 (GREEK LETTER YOT) changed their *General Category* from *Lo* to *Ll*.
- Unicode 3.0.0: U+04C0 (CYRILLIC LETTER PALOCHKA) changed its *General Category* from *Lo* to *Lu*.
- Unicode 4.1.0: U+A015 (YI SYLLABLE WU) changed its *General Category* from *Lo* to *Lm*.
- Unicode 5.0.0: U+10341 (GOTHIC LETTER NINETY) changed its *General Category* from *Lo* to *Nl*.
- Unicode 6.0: U+0CF1 (KANNADA SIGN JIHVAMULIYA), U+0CF2 (KANNADA SIGN UPADHMANIYA) changed their *General Category* from *So* to *Lo*.
- Unicode 6.0: U+19DA (NEW TAI LUE THAM DIGIT ONE) changed its *General Category* from *Nd* to *No*.
- The Cherokee proposal itself proposes to change existing Cherokee characters from *Lo* to *Ll*.

The Unicode Stability Policy is at http://www.unicode.org/policies/stability_policy.html. In particular, for Unicode 2.0 and above, once a character is encoded, it will not be moved or removed and its name will not be changed; for Unicode 5.0 and above, named character sequences, and formal aliases, once assigned to a character, will not be changed or removed.

Comment: With the amount of work that went into this answer, I think it's the clear candidate for the bounty right now. I'm going to read over the answers in some more detail later, but for now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to [the current UNICODE publication dates](http://www.unicode.org/history/publicationdates.html), the following values would be possible (and maximally specific):

- 199110L
- 199206L
- 199306L
- 199507L
- 199607L
- 199805L
- 199808L
- 199812L
- 199904L
- 199909L
- 200009L
- 200103L
- 200203L
- 200304L
- 200503L
- 200607L
- 200803L
- 200910L
- 201201L
- 201209L
- 201309L
- 201406L

However, note that C (and C++) only have a few standards: 89, 90, 95, 99, 03(C++), and 11 (with provisional 14 in the future). Wide characters didn't come around until 95!

This implies only a small selection of these values will reasonably be encountered; on my (reasonably) up to date system (gcc version 4.6.3), I get 200009L.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, though, the ISO publication dates are somewhat different/delayed...

Comment: @R.. Doesn't matter. They don't work off of the actual publication dates, only the date it's formalized. This is pretty standard convention.

Comment: @Alice: Who are "they" and what does "formalized" mean?

Answer (score 2):

**6.10.8 Predefined macro names 2**

> An integer constant of the form yyyymmL (for example, 199712L). If
>   this symbol is defined, then every character in the Unicode required
>   set, when stored in an object of type wchar_t, has the same value as
>   the short identifier of that character. The Unicode required set
>   consists of all the characters that are defined by ISO/IEC 10646,
>   along with all amendments and technical corrigenda, as of the
>   specified year and month.

Comment: Yes, but what are the possible values? There's only one example value in the text of the standard, and I can't find any data on what the other possible values are.

Comment: _what are the possible values?_ : `yyyymmL`

Comment: ISO refurbishment date was able to compiler implementors to comply with the compiler to release.

Comment: I don't understand your most recent comment.

Comment: @R.. It represent a long integer constant yyyymmL if value of wchar_t  in compliance with the revision of the year yyyy month mm of ISO 10646.

Comment: And the whole question is: what are those year/month values for each revision? I've not found any published list that includes the months, only the years.

Comment: @R.. I read the answer as "can be any date". No one says it is a date where the ISO/IEC 10646 was published/revised. You are asking for the list of all ISO/IEC 10646 publishs plus all amendments and technical corrigenda publishs!?

Comment: @WernerHenze: Perhaps your comment is getting at my misunderstanding. The intent of my question was to know these "boundary values" corresponding to the publication months, but I was mistakenly thinking the value needed to be equal to one of them, rather than inherently meaning "latest at the time".

Comment: Also, what does "defined by ISO/IEC 10646..." actually mean? What [stage](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/resources-for-technical-work/stages_table.htm) of the standard does it refer to? Stage `60.60` (published) or stage `90.93` (confirmed)? The current standard is in stage `90.92` (to be revised)...

Comment: @WernerHenze It can't be read as "can be any date"; it specifically says "as defined by ISO/IEC 10646, along with all amendments"; if there was no amendment, technical corrigenda, etc, on a specific date, then it cannot be that date. Pure and simple.

Answer (score 2):

The question does not have an ultimate answer, as further versions of the standard are likely to be released.

Also, the authoritative temporary answer is [worth 198 Swiss Francs](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=56921) and copyrighted.

Comment: The contents are of course not free, but the exact publication date should be. Is the `Stage: 90.92 (2012-11-21)` on that page an official publication date? If so, that suggests a way to get the answer.

Comment: 1/ sorry for making this the answer. New here, not enough points to comment the question.

2/ I am not quite sure the date is the official date, but i asuume it is the case.


3/ Also, i do not know, if the ISO website gives a full list of versions of the standard.

4/ I as far as I remember, there is a revision history in ISO standard printouts. 

Also, an ISO standard may by withdrawn. It is not clear what would happen to possible values of the macro in question.

Comment: This question DOES have an ultimate answer; he is asking what values it may take (present progressive), not the values it may take in the future. Just because the standard may be expanded in the future does not mean that, currently, there are only a fixed set of values it may take. We do not live in the infinite future, but in the present.

Comment: No doubt. Yet you normally want your code to be maintenence free. Obviously this can be only partly sucessfull. My point was that uou cannot get rid of the dependency on activities of the ISO, which is rather unpleasant. Unexpected values od the macro should be handled properly.

Comment: @R..: The [`90.92` stage](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/resources-for-technical-work/stages_table.htm#s90) means "International Standard to be revised". The [10646:2012](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=56921) standard is dated 2012-06-01, which I presume is the publication date, but it is currently in the `90.92` stage with a date of 2012-11-21.

Comment: @user3768029 I don't particularly find that compelling; I want my code to be bug free, but it rarely is. Furthermore, this does not introduce maintenance issues; all dates will be larger in the future (obviously), so you just say greater than the date you need support from. The lack of knowledge of future dates in no way imposes maintenance issues; you can't program against future updates by definition.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive list as the answer is library version specific.

If your code must depend on a particular version of Unicode (say 1997), then you must code for  the possibility that 1997 is not available but 1998 is, and fail gracefully if the library doesn't support the one you want.

Then it comes down to:

```
if(__STDC_ISO_10646__ % 199700)
{
}
else if(__STDC_ISO_10646__ & 199800)
{
}
```

Comment: Untrue; the macro is defined as being pinned to the publication dates of the specification. It's not library specific; any library giving dates other than the ones defined by the specification is not a valid library.

Comment: @Alice: How do you find out the publication dates of earlier versions of the 10646 standard?

Comment: @Alice: How do you know that the macro refers to the year and month of the publication of the 10646 standard? What if it refers to whatever version of the 10646 standard that was in effect at the year and month the C library was published? Has there been a defect report to clarify this issue?

Comment: @NisseEngström "__STDC_ISO_10646__ An integer constant of the form yyyymmL (for example, 199712L). If this symbol is defined, then every character in the Unicode required set, when stored in an object of type wchar_t, has the same value as the short identifier of that character. The Unicode required set consists of all the characters that are defined by ISO/IEC 10646, along with all amendments and technical corrigenda, as of the specified year and month. If some other encoding is used, the macro shall not be defined and the actual encoding used is implementation-defined."